# Why are these animes called so? (something;something)

Tags: tropes

There are manga/anime called "something;something", what for? does it server any purpose for identifying it as a series? example: steins;gate, robotic;notes.

Comment: There are, afaik, only three of these (namely, Chaos;Head, Steins;Gate, and Robotics;Notes). All three of them are part of the so-called "Science Adventure" series. I find it not terribly surprising that a series of games/anime would use the same naming quirks throughout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Wikipedia entry for [Steins;Gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steins;Gate) begins with the following two sentences (emphasis mine):

> Steins;Gate (シュタインズ・ゲート Shutainzu Gēto?) is a Japanese visual novel developed by 5pb. and Nitroplus and released for the Xbox 360 on October 15, 2009. **It is the second game in 5pb. and Nitroplus' Science Adventure series following Chaos;Head and was succeeded by Robotics;Notes.**

---

The entry for [Robotics;Notes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robotics;Notes) is fairly similar:

> Robotics;Notes (ロボティクス・ノーツ Robotikusu Nōtsu?) is a Japanese visual novel developed and published by 5pb.. The game was released on the PlayStation 3 and Xbox 360 video game consoles on June 28, 2012, with a PlayStation Vita port released on June 26, 2014 under the title Robotics;Notes Elite. **It is the third game in 5pb.'s Science Adventure series following Chaos;Head and Steins;Gate** and is described as an "Augmented Science Adventure" (拡張科学アドベンチャー Kakuchō Kagaku Adobenchā?).

---

Finally, the entry for [Science Adventure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science_Adventure) reveals the following:

> The Science Adventure series (科学アドベンチャーシリーズ Kagaku Adobenchā Shirīzu?) is a Japanese video game franchise created by 5pb. in collaboration with Nitroplus. **The series currently consists of four main visual novel games; Chaos;Head, Steins;Gate, Robotics;Notes, and Chaos;Child** which have each received various ports, sequels, and spin-offs, as well as various manga and anime adaptations.

---

So, yes, it is as you assumed: They're part of the same series, made by the same company.

As for why the developers decided to use a semicolon in the name: why not?